# Replicating conditional formatting Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, string-formatting, replication, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a simple table that I can just replicate over and over when needed. Although in my sheet, I have the first range, B3:D12 working exactly as I want, I am finding it a challenge to then copy the formatting across to E3:G12 and for it to work subsequently.

Is the formula wrong? Is there an easier way that I can do this to make it simple each time I copy + paste the table across?

Thanks

[Google Sheet Conditional Formatting](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10JV2teSru_8_Ba5EVCEqAG4GX3_QRkxRVuUIjJbKUXk/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply this:

```
=(B3=D3)*(B3<>"")
```

to `B3:12`, `C3:12` and `D3:12` as green

then as red use:

```
=(B3<>D3)*(B3<>"")
```

on `B3:12`

[image]

Comment: thanks that seems to work great! I think I became unstuck not knowing each of the 3 columns need to be done separately! Please can you briefly explain the logic behind the formatting?

Comment: @Fennomenon logic is simple. we don treat B,C,D columns as a group but only check if B=D and then we offset it by 1 and 2 columns via range (hence the formula for green is always the same just the range is shifting)